# After selecting "My billing information is the same...." an Edit button is shown

Tags: commerce

QQ - When registered user goes through their cart to their payment information the "My billing information is the same as my shipping information. - Optional" is shown as default checked.

When they uncheck this box an **Edit** button appears. Is there any way to stop the edit button from appearing and simply show the fields? This happens when the user has NO address stored. So it's not very intuitive what the next step is.

[image]

[image]

In the CSS, on a working site I notice `id="shipping-information-wrapper"`

On my broken site, that div is not on the page. Instead, this is provided:

```
<div data-drupal-selector="edit-shipping-information-shipping-profile" id="edit-shipping-information-shipping-profile" class="js-form-wrapper form-wrapper">
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it sounds like a bug report that must be reported to the involved module's issue queue on drupal.org to be fixed there. Can you reproduce the same in a fresh install? Or are there any other module's involved? What happens when you click the button? And what exactly is your question?

Comment: I think it's a reasonable question given the ordinary function of the Commerce 2.x address book. I don't see a bug report in here.

Comment: @leymannx not a module bug. pretty sure something on my site is causing but not sure what. additional details provided

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out - The commerce Autosku module had a bug which is fixed here:
https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce/issues/3086575

I decided to remove it entirely though as it doesn't work as well in D8 as it did in D7.

Answer (score 0):

Given the screenshot you've shared, it appears your theme is adding that "- Optional" suffix to the checkbox label. I'm not sure if the theme is getting in the way of anything else, but it's worth looking into.

Out of the box, there's no way to have it show form fields first. We opted for the "Edit" button approach based on fairly extensive usability research. Making the edit operation explicit ensures we don't accidentally create duplicate addresses when the address book select list is present. I don't know what it isn't visible in your screenshot, to be honest. It should be, and if the customer doesn't have any addresses yet, then they should be seeing the form fields immediately like so:

[image]

Comment: First - Thank you for your response! The user does NOT have an existing address.. I've created a fresh account to test and make sure there was nothing. On the EDIT and RECALCULATE buttons are shown. The form fields for new users do not display. I'll added another screenshot and CSS code from a working site and css from my site. Hopefully this helps narrow it down. Thanks again for helping Ryan